# Как установить Линукс?

Tags: linux

Недавно появилось желание установить Линукс, но этого делать ни разу не пробовал. Сейчас стоит Виндовс, (знаю что статей на эту тему много, но как-то я скачивал руководство и собственно сам Линукс и по руководству ничего установить не смог).

1. Статьи, которые наверняка помогут?
2. Версию Линукса, самую хорошую для изучения?
3. И что-то типа Линукс для чайника, хорошее руководство, в котором разобраться не составило больших проблем.
4. Можно ли его установить, не форматируя жестяк полностью?
5. Можно ли установить его вместе с виндой?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Скачиваете дистрибутив: [Download Ubuntu Desktop](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).
2. Устанавливаете программу: [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).
3. Используя программу, записываете скачанный образ на флэшку размером не менее 1 Гб.
4. Перезагружаете ноутбук и грузитесь с флэшки.
5. Выбираете русский язык и следуюте по шагам за мастером установки.

В принципе и все. Установить Ubuntu Linux можно в отдельный раздел диска. Подробнее: [Установка Ubuntu](http://help.ubuntu.ru/manual/%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Читать для ознакомления с возможностями: [Руководство по Ubuntu](http://help.ubuntu.ru/manual/%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас ноутбук и/или есть доп. оборудование(принтер, тв-карта, 3G-модем и.т.д.), то стоит для начала убедиться в наличии драйверов. Будет обидно, если после установки вдруг обнаружится, что wi-fi не работает, а у тачпада не работает мультитач. Такое, к сожалению, не редкость. А так дистрибы между собой мало различаются

Answer (score 0):

Я бы рекомендовал начинать изучение линукс с Дистрибутива "Росинка"... Он основан на Ubuntu и имеет более дружественный интерфейс, а когда привыкните, можете уже и другие линуксы попробывать )))

Answer (score 0):

Если привыкли к Windows, то лучше Mint. Устанавливается просто, потом через интернет русифицируется. Сам начинал с Mandrak, потом пользовался Mandriva - интерфейс более дружественный, нежели у Ubuntu. Проблема в том, что в Mandriva произошли сильные изменения, сейчас пытаюсь перейти на OpenSuse или Mageia - в обоих вариантах есть свои проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Лично я рекомендую Убунту 10.04!

Объясню.

Я длительное время "сидел" на Винде и меня "замахала" необходимость ее переустанавливать, т.к. люблю поэкспериментировать с различными программами.

В свое время я ставил Линукс Сюзи, Мандриву.

Итог: не понравилась, т.к. сложно было "перестроиться" с Винды на эти версии Линукса.

Чем меня привлекла Убунту? Своей гибкостью и (самое главное) возможностью настроить интерфейс под привычный мне Виндовс!

И возможность длительной легальной (законной) поддержки - тоже немаловажное обстоятельство!

Answer (score 0):

Раз речь идет о рекомендацих выскажу свое субъективное мнение,лично считаю,что изучение-познание Linux не следует начинать с "легких" дистрибутивов, а выбрать что-то среднее напр.с линейки Fedora,-- почему хотя-бы потому,что легкость вызывает некое привыкание,а вообще-то наверно и,лучше всего, сначала посмотреть-попробовать-пощупать используя виртуальную машину,так сказать протестировать себя и железо, на совместимость.Не ужились --удалил виртуалку и попрощались,понравилось - подошло,тогда можно уже и устанавливать