# Как снести Windows с последующей установкой Linux?

Tags: linux, windows

Путешествуя в бескрайних просторах Интернета я не смог ответить на заветный и непонятный мне, как новичку вопрос: Как снести винду и установить Линукс?

Объясните мне пожалуйста, попроще, как для чайника.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Инсталятор Linux в самом начале попросит создать разделы на диске подходящего типа. на этом этапе вы можете удалить разделы windows и на их месте создать линуксовые

Comment: Все просто, определитесь какая ОС у вас будет установлена, далее зайдите на ее офф сайт и скачайте её, далее создайте загрузочную флешку с этой ОС используя любую пригодную для вас утилиту, далее сам процесс установки. Во время процесса выберите "удалить виндовс" ну и там по порядку

Comment: я не знаю как после скачивания установить на компьютер. Можно пошаговую инструкцию?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Вы создали загрузочный диск или загрузочную флешку с данной ОС? Если нет то это первый шаг

Comment: а как это сделать?

Comment: Например [через эту программу](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/unetbootin)

Comment: [И прочитайте все вот тут. Удачи!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/339396/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%9b%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%81)

Comment: И да, раз у вас встал такой базовый вопрос, напоминаю, что установка новой операционной системы уничтожит все данные на системном жёстком диске, включая ваши личные. Поэтому скопируйте все ваши файлы куда-нибудь за пределы компьютера, например, на внешний жёсткий диск.

Comment: И еще один момент 14.04 уже старенькая (поддержка скоро закончиться), ставьте 16.04 LTS, вот вот выйдет 18.04

Comment: И еще [вот этот активный блог](http://compizomania.blogspot.com/), он мне когда-то помог со всем разобраться